# VB.net get item value in string array

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, json.net

This is my code :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim JsonSub As String = "{""subdomain01"":[""21"",""subdomain01"",""4""],""subdomain02"":[""22"",""subdomain02"",""4""]}"
    Dim objSub As JObject = JObject.Parse(JsonSub)
    Dim dataSub As List(Of JToken) = objSub.Children().ToList

    For Each subdomain As JProperty In dataSub
        subdomain.CreateReader()
        For Each pSub As JObject In subdomain.Value.ToString
            MsgBox(pSub.ToString)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

How can I get value in array of that string :

> [""21"",""subdomain01"",""4""]

Comment: Change `For Each pSub As JObject In subdomain.Value.ToString` to `For Each pSub As String In subdomain.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get just that, do a split:

```
Dim resultarray As String() = JsonSub.Split(":")(1).Split(",")
Dim result As String = resultarray(0) & "," & resultarray(1) & "," & resultarray(2)
```

as JsonSub.Split(CChar(":"))(1) will return [""21"",""subdomain01"",""4""],""subdomain02""

and in turn, split that with the comma will net you 4 substring between those ",". You only need to take the first 3, and the result is as shown.